# "" after the = in the Javascript gives an error because there is a "" in the html code that is in the Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

there is a "" in my html code so the js won't understand which "" should use i guess , any good suggest for that !!!

```
document.getElementById("prja").innerHTML =/"
< div class=" container - fluid" >
    < div class="row" >
        <div class="col h1 mt-3 mb-5 text-center font-weight-bolder mb-3 mt-5"
            style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; color: rgb(2, 151, 151); ">
            Our Projects
    </div>
    </div >
</div >
/";
```

Comment: what's up with the `/"` at the start and end of your String? What's the `/` for?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to just use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
document.getElementById("prja").innerHTML = `
  <div class=" container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col h1 mt-3 mb-5 text-center font-weight-bolder mb-3 mt-5"
           style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; color: rgb(2, 151, 151);">
        Our Projects
      </div>
     </div >
  </div>`;
```

```html
<div id="prja"></div>
```

---

If, for some reason, you want to continue using a regular double quoted string instead:

1. You should escape the inner double quotes, not the outer ones.
2. Escaping is done by placing a backslash before the quotes (`\"`), not a forward slash.
3. You have to replace the newlines with newline characters (`\n`).

Comment: about 3. you can also escape linebreaks in regular strings with a backslash. That looks then like a line ending with a `\ `. But template strings are all around easier/better.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this following way:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div class='container - fluid'><div class='row'><div class='col h1 mt-3 mb-5 text-center font-weight-bolder mb-3 mt-5' style='font-family: /'Oswald/', sans-serif; color: rgb(2, 151, 151); '>Our Projects</div></div><div>";
```

Or take a look at JavaScript multi-line String that can also solve this problem